# Two ways of instantiating NSArrays in Objective-C, what is the difference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, oop

To instantiate NSArrays I've always used:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

But recently I've seen an example where NSArrays are being instantiated like every other object by allocating NSArray object:

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

Is there a difference between the two ways of instantiating an array object?

Comment: Are you kidding?  Did you even *look* at the related questions when you submitted this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744468/what-is-the-difference-between-arraywithobjects-and-initwithobjects?rq=1

Comment: Two words: memory management.  And now you're better off using `@[@"one",@"two",@"three"]` instead of the first.

Answer (score 0):

In first case created object is autoreleased, but in second case you have to release object manually when it's no longer needed. Of course, this is valid in case you are managing memory manually, but in case of ARC it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Not 100% sure of the ARC implementation details, but I would think the first still sticks it in the auto release pool but the second releases immediately, so there is a minor effect to be aware of.